# DAX/PowerBI - looking up rate and multiplying by hours

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have three tables

Rates:

```
Rate ID, Rate, Per Hour
1, A, 10
2, B, 20
3, C, 30
```

Staff

```
Staff ID, Name, Rate
1, Bob,    A
2, Fred,   B
3, Shelly, C
4, George, C
```

Timesheet

```
Timesheet ID, Staff ID, Hours
1, 1, 30
2, 2, 30
3, 2, 30
4, 1, 60
5, 3, 30
6, 4, 60
```

I am using

```
Total Hours worked =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Timesheet[Hours] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Timesheet' ), 'Timesheet'[Staff ID] = Staff[Staff ID] )
)
```

To look up my hours and total them

I'm trying to lookup the rates from the rate table

```
Rate Per Hr = LOOKUPVALUE(Rates[ Per Hour],Rates[Rates],Staff[Rate])
```

But I get an error about single values.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong on this one!  Any help?  I've been using PowerBI for about two days and not really done a lot of DAX.

Frankly, I don't need to replicate the data in the table from Rates, just do the calculation which is total hours worked * hourly rate

Answer (score 0):

Gah

Measure = sumx('Staff','Staff'[Total Hours worked] * RELATED('Rates'[ Per Hour]))

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways I guess. The first would be to use calculated columns in the staff table to calculated the components and subsequently the total rate * hours worked.

```
Rate per Hour = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Rates[Per Hour] ) ;
        FILTER( ALL( Rates ) ; Staff[Rate] = Rates[Rate] )
    )
```

And

```
Hours worked = 
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Timesheet[Hours] ) ;
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Timesheet' ) ; 'Timesheet'[Staff ID] = Staff[Staff ID] )
    )
```

Resulting in

```
Total = Staff[Hours worked] * Staff[Rate per Hour]
```

An alternative (my preference) would be using measures and forcing row context using the iterator SUMX. One could opt to split in three measures or to group all into one as shown in the below example

```
Total = 
    SUMX ( 
        Staff ; 

        var _hoursWorked = 
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( Timesheet[Hours] ) ;
                FILTER ( ALL ( 'Timesheet' ) ; 'Timesheet'[Staff ID] = Staff[Staff ID] )
            )

        var _ratePerHr = 
            CALCULATE ( 
                SUM ( Rates[Per Hour] ) ;
                FILTER( ALL( Rates ) ; Staff[Rate] = Rates[Rate] )
            )

        RETURN
            _ratePerHr * _hoursWorked
    )
```